# Subclassing 'PDFView' in swift - cannot find interface declaration

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, pdfkit, pdfview

I am trying to make a subclass of PDFKit's PDFView in my macOS application, which has legacy objective-c code as part of the project.

My swift class looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import Quartz

class customPDFView: PDFView
{
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

During the build I get an error in my 'projectName-Swift.h' file, which has created this:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC5NVivo13customPDFView")
@interface customPDFView : PDFView
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

The second line in the above code produces the error:
`Cannot find interface declaration for 'PDFView', superclass of 'customPDFView'`

Note: My 'projectName.h' file includes both lines `@import Foundation` and `@import Quartz`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `import Cocoa`

Comment: @LeoDabus unfortunately that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer so will post if anyone else ever stumbles across this issue.

In my `<projectName>-Bridging-Header.h` file I added in the line `#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>` and this solved the issue!